# Finding folders on PC with fewer than five files inside

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-search, file-search

Is it possible to find folders that contain fewer than five files inside?

Comment: Are you familiar with "batch scripts" with command prompt? Or powershell scripts? There are definitely answers involving these tools, but maybe you'd rather have a solution with an easy to use GUI?

Comment: Yes it is. Like Romen says, can you explain a little more what you're looking for? But also, what research have you done yourself trying to figure this out? We don't want to duplicate what you've already tried, but we also are not a script writing service nor to we recommend software products.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Powershell script to find out which folders on your system has 5 or fewer files and list that on the screen.

Here's a script that does this.

```
$collection = get-childitem -Directory -Recurse -Path "C:\"

$list = @()

$collection | ForEach-Object {
    $foldername = $_.FullName
    $items = (get-childitem -Path $foldername).count

    if( $items -le 5 ) {
        $list += $foldername
    }
}

$list
```